# How to rename complicated variable name in fixest etable

Tags: r, fixest

I'm wondering how to change a complex variable name with `dict` in `etable` in `fixest` package.

For example, I have a regression `Y ~ x1 + x2:abs(x3):x4` and I'd like to change the name of `x2:abs(x3):x4`.

I have tried

```
etable(...,
dict = c(`x2:abs(x3):x4` = 'myvar')
)
```

```
etable(...,
dict = c("x2:abs(x3):x4" = 'myvar')
)
```

```
etable(...,
dict = c("x2*abs(x3)*x4" = 'myvar')
)
```

But no success. Is there a easy fix for this?

Comment: `etable` is a bit of a hack, have you considered trying `modelsummary`, `texreg`, `huxreg` in `huxtable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. It's likely a version problem:

```
library(fixest)
est = feols(mpg ~ cyl:abs(disp):hp, mtcars)
etable(est, dict=c("cyl:abs(disp):hp" = "New coef"))
#>                                  est
#> Dependent Var.:                  mpg
#>                                     
#> (Intercept)        25.05*** (0.9560)
#> New coef        -1.65e-5*** (2.3e-6)
#> _______________ ____________________
#> S.E. type                   Standard
#> Observations                      32
#> R2                           0.63073
#> Adj. R2                      0.61842
```

Otherwise, please provide a minimal reproducible example.